# How to configure Nginx with gunicorn and bokeh serve

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn, bokeh

I want to serve a flask app that uses embedded bokeh serve from a server on my local network. To illustrate I made an example using the [bokeh serve example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.11/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_gunicorn_embed.py) and a docker image to replicate the server. The docker image runs Nginx and Gunicorn. I think there is a problem with my nginx configuration routing the requests to the /bkapp uri.

I have detailed the problem and provided all source code in the following [git repo](https://github.com/donoghuc/bokeh_recipe/tree/master/single_container)

I have started a discussion on [bokeh google group](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/8Y1rNJ0XBOc)

## Single Container

In order to reduce the complexity of running nginx in its own container I built this image that runs nginx in same container as the web app

### Installation

NOTE: I am using Docker version 17.09.0-ce

Download or clone repo and navigate to this directory (single_container).

```
# as root
docker build -f Dockerfile -t single_container .
```

[build](https://github.com/donoghuc/bokeh_recipe/blob/master/screenshots/docker_build.png)

start a terminal session in new container

```
# as root
docker run -ti single_container:latest
```

In new container start nginx

```
nginx
```

now start gunicorn

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b :8000 flask_gunicorn_embed:app
```

[start](https://github.com/donoghuc/bokeh_recipe/blob/master/screenshots/start_container.png)

in a separate terminal (on host machine) find the IP address of the single_container container you are running

```
#as root
docker ps
# then do copy CONTAINER ID and inspect it
docker inspect [CONTIANER ID] | grep IPAddress
```

[find](https://github.com/donoghuc/bokeh_recipe/blob/master/screenshots/find_ip_single.png)

## PROBLEM

Using IP found above (with container running) check out in firefox with inspector.
As you can in screenshot above (see screenshots folder "single_container_broken.png" for raw the get request just hangs

[broke_1](https://github.com/donoghuc/bokeh_recipe/blob/master/screenshots/single_container_broken.png)

I can verify that nginx is serving the static files though by navigating to /bkapp/static/ (see bokeh_recipe/single_container/nginx/bokeh_app.conf for config)

[static](https://github.com/donoghuc/bokeh_recipe/blob/master/screenshots/can_serve_static.png)

Another oddidy is that I try to hit the embedded bokeh server directly (with /bkapp/) but i end up with a 400 (denied?)

[bkapp](https://github.com/donoghuc/bokeh_recipe/blob/master/screenshots/hit_bkapp.png)

## Note about app

- to reduce complexity of dynamically assigning available ports to tornado workers I hard coded in 46518 for port to talk to bokeh serve

## nginx config

I know you could just look at bokeh_recipe/single_container/nginx/bokeh_app.conf but I want to show it here. 
I think I need to config nginx to make explicit that the "request" to bkapp to the 127.0.0.1:46518 is originating FROM the server not the client.

```
## Define the parameters for a specific virtual host/server
server {

    # define what port to listen on
    listen 80;

    # Define the specified charset to the “Content-Type” response header field
    charset utf-8;

    # Configure NGINX to deliver static content from the specified folder
    # NOTE this should be a docker volume shared from the bokehrecipe_web container (css, js for bokeh serve)
    location /bkapp/static/ {
        alias /home/flask/app/web/static/;
        autoindex on;
    }

    # Configure NGINX to reverse proxy HTTP requests to the upstream server (Gunicorn (WSGI server))
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
   # deal with the http://127.0.0.1/bkapp/autoload.js (note hard coded port for now)
    location /bkapp/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:46518;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you solve the problem?